# JOOQ - Is it possible to generate code for specific columns in table?

Tags: java, jooq

Is it possible to generate code for specific columns in table ?

Comment: But in all seriousness, if you want a better answer, ask a more thorough question: include information about how you are implementing the table, include code (code is good), be specific about what you need, etc...  Good luck!

Comment: i wish to exclude most of the columns from autogenerated crud records and do not use them at all

Comment: @Enigmadan: While you're right in general, in this particular case, the question is clear enough...

Comment: @LukasEder Thanks for clarifying that.  I guess I jumped the gun in condemning this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this feature has been added to jOOQ 3.2. You can now specify whether your code generator's `<include/>` and `<exclude/>` elements should also match columns by adding the following flag:

```xml
<!-- This flag indicates whether include / exclude patterns should also match
     columns within tables. --> 
<includeExcludeColumns>true</includeExcludeColumns>
```

For more info, see:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/